# Performing boxing when invoking method

Tags: java, methods, boxing

Why does not method handle perform boxing of primitive types?

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodType;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static int i(int i1, Integer i2){
        return i1 + i2;
    }
    public static void tm() throws Throwable {
        MethodHandles.Lookup lu = MethodHandles.publicLookup();
        MethodType mt = MethodType.methodType(int.class, int.class, int.class);
        MethodHandle mh = lu.findStatic(Ideone.class, "i", mt);
        System.out.println(mh.invoke(1, 2));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        tm();
    }

}
```

https://ideone.com/KmvNkx

Here is the code I tried. It throws an exception. I expected the `MethodHandle::invoke`, not `invokeExact` performs `asType` adjusting, including boxing conversion. What's wrong?

Comment: The error is `IllegalAccessException: symbolic reference class is not public` which is understandable : `publicLookup` can only lookup... public classes (as stated in the javadoc), but your class does not have the public modifier. Change to `public class Ideone` and you'll get a step further. By the way : its always good to say what is your error, and not just "It throws an exception".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you've got two problems here:

1) Your class isn't public, which the publicLookup() requires. So change your class declaration to this:

```
public class Ideone
{
```

2) Auto-boxing/unboxing is a convenience during compilation and runtime that hides the fact that primative int and class Integer are different. Your look up on the method is looking for a method called "i" that returns a primative int and has two primative int parameters. And that's not the case. So change your lookup to this, which matches the function declaration:

```
MethodType mt = MethodType.methodType(int.class, int.class, Integer.class);
MethodHandle mh = lu.findStatic(Ideone.class, "i", mt);
```